# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}[1,~2,~\ldots,~n]}$ irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, irrational-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\text{lcm}[1,~2,~\ldots,~n]} $$
an irrational number? I just thought up of the problem, and can anyone help this out?

Comment: Show please your attempts

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h511659p2874098